# How do I format the output to include the function definition?

Tags: formatting, display

To explain, I do most of my probability homework in Mathematica, and use the typesetting built into Mathematica to finish answers. Often, I want to output a function as the answer to a problem, but I want it to be explicit, that is, in the example below, I create a function, `X[x,y,z]`, and I want the result to not just display the (in this case) piecewise function, but I want it to define it as a function. As an example:

```
Clear[X, x, y, z]
X[x_, y_, z_] := Piecewise[{{3/(4*Pi), Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] <= 1}}, 0]
X[x, y, z]//TraditionalForm
```

The output of this is
$$
 \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{3}{4 \pi } & \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\leq 1 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \right.
$$

I want it (the *output*) to look (something) like

$$
 X(x,y,z)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{3}{4 \pi } & \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\leq 1 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \right.
$$

Comment: Perhaps `HoldForm[X[x, y, z]] == X[x, y, z] // TraditionalForm`?

Comment: Yeah, that seems to pretty much do what I want it to. I think I'd prefer it without the parenthesis it puts around the piecewise equation, but it does give me the result I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To expand my comment into an answer:

```
HoldForm[X[x, y, z]] == X[x, y, z] // TraditionalForm
```

$$X(x,y,z)=\left(
 \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{3}{4 \pi } & \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\leq 1 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \right.
\right)$$

But Mathematica decides it needs parentheses.  I agree that this doesn't look ideal.  There are a couple of ways around it.  One is that you can manually edit the traditional form in Mathematica.  Another option is to piece it together ourselves in a `Row` (with a goofy equals to nothing):

```
Clear[traditionalise];
Attributes[traditionalise] = {HoldAll};
traditionalise[f_] := TraditionalForm@Row@{HoldForm@f == " ", f}

traditionalise[X[x,y,z]]
```

$$
 X(x,y,z)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{3}{4 \pi } & \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\leq 1 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \right.
$$

Comment: In Alpha, we usually do something like `Row[{HoldForm[f], " \[LongEqual] ", f}] // TraditionalForm`.

Comment: @Chip Why not `Row[{HoldForm[f], f}, "\[LongEqual]"]`?  I believe that uses the proper spacing rules.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I guess I stretched the truth a bit. The idiom I referred to is used in other custom `Row`-like constructs.