# Output function definition as TeXForm with big bracket

Tags: formatting, latex, traditional-form

I've checked [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63686/how-do-i-format-the-output-to-include-the-function-definition). While it works in Mathematica, the $\LaTeX$ output is weird.

```
X[x_, y_, z_] := Piecewise[{{3/(4*Pi), Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] <= 1}}, 0]
Row[{HoldForm[X[x, y, z]], X[x, y, z]}, "\[LongEqual]"] // TraditionalForm // TeXForm
```

The $\LaTeX$ output is:

```
X(x,y,z)=
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{3}{4 \pi } & \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\leq 1 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
```

which renders as:

[image]

How could I get something like:

[image]

?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
toX[s_]:=ToString@TeXForm[s]
X[x_,y_,z_]:=Piecewise[{{3/(4*Pi),Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]<=1}},0]
toX[HoldForm@X[x,y,z]]<>"="<>toX[X[x,y,z]]
```

Which gives

```
X(x,y,z)=\begin{cases}
 \frac{3}{4 \pi } & \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\leq 1 \\
 0 & \text{True}
\end{cases}
```

COPY the above from the notebook using `plain text` to your Latex editor outside of Mathematica:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}   
\[
X(x,y,z)=\begin{cases}
 \frac{3}{4 \pi } & \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\leq 1 \\
 0 & \text{True}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Compiled using TeXLive gives

[image]

---

Or if you have MaTeX installed in Mathematica, you can compile the output without leaving the comfort of the notebook:

[image: Mathematica graphics]